# elasticsearch_dsl filter out data in a field containing a specific character

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a dataset containing windows event logs, I am trying to filter out values in a field TargetUserName that contain a specific character of say #.

basically, if TargetUserName contains # do not aggregate it. Below is my current code.

```
    es = Elasticsearch([localhostmines], timeout=30)
    s = Search(using=es, index="logindex-*").filter('term', EventID="4624").filter('term', TargetUserName="*#")

    users = set([])
    for hit in s.scan():
        users.add(hit.TargetUserName)

    print(users)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We need to know the mapping of the `TargetUserName` field. Can you run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/logindex-2017-01-05` and provide the output you get?

Comment: {"type" : "text","fields":{"keyword" : {"keyword", "ignore_above":256}}}, "TargetUserName" : {"type": "text", "fields" :{"keyword":

Comment: That's everything on the line of the TargetUserName. I was asked not to submit the entire log. Is there anything else that is needed?

Comment: That's good, you can use the field called `TargetUserName.keyword` instead of just `TargetUserName` in the aggregation part. As for the filter you can try `.filter('wildcard', 'TargetUserName.keyword'='*#')`

Comment: I get a SyntaxError stating Keyword cant be an expression.

Comment: If you have dots in your field names you can replace them in keyword arguments with double underscore, so: `.filter('wildcard', TargetUserName__keyword='*#')` should work